# How do I reliably determine the window handle of a given Outlook inspector window with WordMail turned on from inside a COM-Addin (Outlook <=2003)?

Tags: winapi, outlook, add-in, hwnd

[This code is called from within the `Inspector.Activate` event handler (first call), i.e. right before the inspector window is actually shown.]

For "native" mail inspectors I can simply QI the `Inspector` interface to `IOleWindow` and call its `GetWindow` method. However, this will not work for Word inspectors which are in fact instances of Word with a special toolbar and do not implement `IOleWindow`.

(Temporarily) setting `Inspector.Caption` to some unique value and then looking for a window with that caption also does not work as accessing most properties of the `Inspector` simply has no (immediate) effect on the actual inspector window when using the WordMail option. Neither does calling `Activate` and then immediately querying `GetForegroundWindow` work reliably: when there are multiple inspectors already open or when actual Word windows are present this will often just return the "oldest" instance instead of the most recent one.

I have tried a number of other approaches over the years but they all eventually turned out to be flawed in some way or another. Is there a moderately simple solution to this at all or will I have to go for a much more elaborate approach like keeping my own list of known window handles via a system hook and trying to match them up against the known inspectors somehow? (hat tip to [P Daddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295996/is-the-order-in-which-handles-are-returned-by-enumwindows-meaningful#296014) for the hint about using CBT hooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now come up with something new that I haven't yet been able to break but it still feels a lot like voodoo. By observation I found that the window I want always appears to be the first one returned by [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497.aspx) that is not (yet) visible, i.e. [`IsWindowVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28VS.85%29.aspx) returns `False` (remember I'm calling this code from inside the first occurrence of the `Inspector.Activate` event right before the inspector gets displayed for the first time).

If anyone knows of a better solution or has a well-founded explanation of why this works (preferably with links to authoritative docs), please post a reply.

**Update:** So, by request, here's some actual (Delphi) code. Note that this is not my working code, which contains a couple of other things, not relevant to this question, that have been trimmed out here.

```
function GetWindowClassName(const AHandle: HWND): String;
var
  lClass: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  if GetClassName(AHandle, lClass, SizeOf(lClass)) > 0 then
    Result := lClass
  else
    Result := '';
end;

type
  TWordSearchInfo = record
    Result: HWND;
  end;
  PWordSearchInfo = ^TWordSearchInfo;

function CheckWnd(AWnd: HWND; ASearchInfo: PWordSearchInfo): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    if GetWindowClassName(AWnd) = 'OpusApp' then
      if not IsWindowVisible(AWnd) then
        begin
          ASearchInfo.Result := AWnd;
          Exit(False);
        end;
  except
    //plop!
  end;
end;

function GetNewestWordHandle: Cardinal;
var
  lSearchInfo: TWordSearchInfo;
begin
  lSearchInfo.Result := 0;
  EnumWindows(@CheckWnd, Integer(@lSearchInfo));
  Result := lSearchInfo.Result;
end;
```

**Note:** I only use this function from within the inspector's `Activate`-event and when the Outlook major version is < 12 and the inspector's `IsWordMail`-property is `True`.

Comment: I tried this approach, but the EnumWindows didn't return the wordmail window at all (OpusApp). Did you ever find a better solution? If not, how did you implement the code to get the window?

Comment: @Moox: When do you call `EnumWindows`? I'm not doing anything special there. I'll post some snippets later.

Comment: @Moox: I've added a code snippet to my answer, now. Please take special note of the Note below the snippet regarding the very restricted circumstances under which I make use of this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on the Constructor of the custom Inspector, you can use the following method to find the newly constructed inspector.

C#

`inspectorWindow = Win32.FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "OpusApp", "Microsoft Word");`

You have to do this on the constructor, afterwards the caption becomes the title of the message ("Untitled Message" on new messages). I'm assuming that if you have a message named Microsoft Word already opened, there could be an error because of ambiguity, but the chances that it happens are somewhat low.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that this would also find actual Word windows which also have a class name of "OpusApp". Apart from that, I don't have a custom inspector: I'm hooking into the existing ones via event handlers.