# Can I always be sure of the hierarchical order of controls found via FindWindowEx?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, vba, winapi

### What am I doing?

I am automating a 3rd party application. The login window looks like this

[image]

*Note: there is a background image embed within the form and both the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` are actually part of an image. Just in case anyone wonders why the below classes treeview from `Window Detective` doesn't have, possibly » `Label` controls.*

[image]

### Where am I at?

I don't have any problems getting handles of components. *I mean, I can generally access each window/control using `FindWindowEx` function*.

I can implement a `GetWindowTextLength` and/or `GetWindowText` functions for buttons to distinguish which one I have got a handle of. While this approach works fine with `Button`s (*.Caption*) it **would not** benefit me when working with `Edit` controls. It seems that the `Edit` controls do not have any unique properties to distinguish which one is which. (*correct me if I am wrong*)...

### The problem

Assume that I need to know at the compile stage which `Edit` control I am going to be handling, *so I don't send a password to the username and other way around*. There are only two but like I've said I'm not sure how to get the *right* one.

I wouldn't mind figuring it out at run-time but I am unsure of how to distinguish the difference without sending a message and actually visually identify which one is which...

### Current solution

I wouldn't really call this a solution but for now I am relying only on the fact that each time I run my code I **always** get a handle of the second (*password*) `Edit` control as the first handle returned.

### Question

Can I be 100% sure the second `Edit` control will always be returned first in the hierarchy returned by the `FindWindowEx` function?

If someone can confirm my idea than I'd already have had a solution **BUT** if I can't **always** expect the second `Edit` control to be returned then I would like to hear some insight on how to handle this situation.

*Note: I didn't think any code is actually required for my question but if anyone would like to see the code then please leave a comment and I will add it to the question.*

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Unless the third party application changes ... have you any reason to think the order of controls will change?

Comment: Not answering, but each child HWND has a property called "ID". Use `GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_ID );` to get it. *Depending* on how the target application is coded, that "id" *may* be a way to distinguish between child control. Knowing the ID you can get the child HWND with the `GetDlgItem` API (works fine when the parent is not a DialogBox, the API should have been called GetChildByID). Beware: some target applications really use random/unreliable values for IDs.

Comment: @Rob for now the 3rd party application will be the same. If it changes I will obviously adjust my code. What I am actually asking is can I be sure that the `FindWindowEx` function always returns handles to windows/controls in the same order?

Comment: @manuell thanks for the tip. I would happy to accept your idea if you convert it to an answer. It turns out that the `GetWindowLongPtr()` function actually returns the ID of the controls (it seems to be constant each time I run my code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each child `HWND` has a property called `ID`. Use `GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_ID )` to get it. Depending on how the target application is coded, that `ID` may be a way to distinguish between child control. Knowing the `ID` you can get the child `HWND` with the `GetDlgItem` API (works fine when the parent is not a DialogBox, the API should have been called `GetChildByID`).

Beware: some target applications really use random/unreliable values for IDs.

It seems that there is a general consensus: Enumeration APIs rely on the Z-Order. See for example that SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/296014/1374704) (maybe making your question some sort of 'duplicate')

While some applications may "play" with the Z-Order of their child windows, in the standard case they won't, which means that the first created child window is at the top of the Z-order, and the last created one is at the bottom.

Comment: I have left a comment for you below my original post as it turns out the approach with `GetWindowLongPtr` works for me :)

Comment: @manuell, answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/296014/1374704 is very inaccurate, I just corrected, see ibid.